# Custom footnote superscript in two column article

Tags: footnotes, two-column

I am writing an article and need footnotes to write author affiliations. I am writing in a two-column format and using `\twocolumn`. I would like the superscripts of the footnote to be custom made, such that the footnote superscript of the first author could be `\dagger 1` and the second could be e,g, `\ddagger 2a`. See the example below

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\begin{center}
Author 1\footnotemark and Author 2\footnotemark
\end{center}
]
\footnotetext{Custom superscript 1: Text}
\footnotetext{Custom superscript 2: Text}

Text \footnote{Ordinary footnote}

\end{document}
```

Right now, the superscript of the two authors is '2'. How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\textsuperscript{<whatever>}` to mimic the footnote representation. Then, `\customfootnotetext{<whatever>}{<footnote text>}` (defined below) can be used to set the actual footnote text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\newcommand{\customfootnotetext}[2]{{% Group to localize change to footnote
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{#1}% Update footnote counter representation
  \footnotetext[0]{#2}}}% Print footnote text

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \centering
  Author 1\textsuperscript{$\dagger$1} and Author 2\textsuperscript{$\ddagger$2a}
]

\customfootnotetext{$\dagger$1}{Custom superscript 1: Text}
\customfootnotetext{$\ddagger$2a}{Custom superscript 2: Text}

Text \footnote{Ordinary footnote}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\begin{center}
Author 1\footnotemark and Author 2\footnotemark
\end{center}
]
\footnotetext[1]{Custom superscript 1: Text}
\footnotetext[2]{Custom superscript 2: Text}

Text \footnote{Ordinary footnote}

\end{document}
```

If the environment inside twocolumn had not a special behavior you could do it as below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
Author 1\footnotemark[1] and Author 2\footnotemark[2]
\end{center}

\footnotetext[1]{Custom superscript 1: Text}
\footnotetext[2]{Custom superscript 2: Text}

Text \footnote[3]{Ordinary footnote}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't allow numbers as optional arguments for some reason and so you have to follow the fix of the first code or something similar.